# Enforcing canonical hostname with ASP.NET Core 1.1 rewrite middleware

Tags: asp.net-core

The documentation for the new URL rewriting middleware in ASP.NET Core 1.1, says "For example, you could ensure a canonical hostname by rewriting any requests to http://example.com to instead be http://www.example.com". Unfortunately, the code for this example is not shown because this is EXACTLY what I am trying to do.

An example is shown as follows...

```
var options = new RewriteOptions()
     .AddRedirect("(.*)/", "$1");
```

This uses a regular expression to redirect any request that has a trailing slash to a URL that doesn't. What I need is the equivalent of this for "redirect to www.*" if it's not already there.

I was able to accomplish this by creating a custom IRule implementation:

```
public class RedirectToWwwRule : IRule
{
    public virtual void ApplyRule(RewriteContext context)
    {
        var host = context.HttpContext.Request.Host;

        if (host.HasValue && !host.Value.StartsWith("www")) {
            var req = context.HttpContext.Request;
            var response = context.HttpContext.Response;

            var newUrl = new StringBuilder()
                .Append("https://www.").Append(host)
                .Append(req.PathBase).Append(req.Path).Append(req.QueryString);

            context.HttpContext.Response.Redirect(newUrl.ToString(), true);
        }
    }
}
```

I am hard-coding "https://" but that's okay in my case. I am thinking there must be a simpler way to do this.

Comment: This would be better handled by the hosting webserver, not your application (because your application should be configurable to run under any hostname). This is done using `<system.webServer>` in your web.config file.

Comment: Can't use <system.webServer>. Deploying to Linux host via docker behind load balancer. Used to use <system.webServer> via UrlWrite module in IIS. Not available to me now.

Comment: Which webserver are you using on the Linux hosts?

Comment: Load balancer is terminating SSL and then forwarding to a cluster of hosts. Each host is running a docker container (ASP.NET Core 1.1 optimized container) that runs my ASP.NET Core process (Kestrel). If I had full control of the load balancer (Nginx), I could do it there but I don't (it'a an AWS ELB). So in other words, 443 to ELB which forwards to Kestrel on 80.